# IDBCursor has different value on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, indexeddb

I had the code below implemented for my cart function. I save the products data locally using IndexedDB before saving the whole cart on the database. On going in the cart via link the code below executes very well. But if I hit refresh or reload it the value of cursor variable is different. I tested to `console.log(cursor.value.pid)` before the ajax request and on success of the ajax. In their I noticed that before the ajax request the value of cursor is still correct but on success of the ajax request it changes to last product and duplicates that product depending on how many items I have in the cart. By the way I use ajax request to get a data from an API for currency conversion.

```
if $('#shopping-cart').length > 0
  request = indexedDB.open('indexedDB', parseInt(1))
  request.onsuccess = (event)->
    db = event.target.result
    objectStore = db.transaction('cart').objectStore('userCart')
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = (event)->
      cursor = event.target.result
      if cursor
        if cursor.value.disPercent > 0
          discounted = parseFloat(cursor.value.price) - (parseFloat(cursor.value.price) * (parseInt(cursor.value.disPercent) / 100))
          $.ajax(
            url: 'api-xxxx'
            dataType: 'json'
            success: (data)->
              if typeof fx != 'undefined' && fx.rates
                fx.rates = data.rates
                currency = $('body').data('to').toUpperCase()
                price = fx(discounted).from(cursor.value.from.toUpperCase()).to(currency)
                $('#shopping-cart-table-body').append(cursor.value.pid)
                                    createOptions cursor.value.pid, cursor.value.inStock, cursor.value.quantity

          )
        else
          $.ajax(
            url: 'api-xxxx'
            dataType: 'json'
            success: (data)->
              if typeof fx != 'undefined' && fx.rates
                fx.rates = data.rates
                currency = $('body').data('to').toUpperCase()
                price = fx(cursor.value.price).from(cursor.value.from.toUpperCase()).to(currency)
                $('#shopping-cart-table-body').append(cursor.value.pid)
                createOptions cursor.value.pid, cursor.value.inStock, cursor.value.quantity
          )
        cursor.continue()

    )
```

**Update:**
I have noticed that it's just on ajax callback. It gives me the same problem if I use the cursors value in 4th level. For example:

```
 if $('#shopping-cart').length > 0
  request = indexedDB.open('indexedDB', parseInt(1))
  request.onsuccess = (event)->
    db = event.target.result
    objectStore = db.transaction('cart').objectStore('userCart')
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = (event)->
      cursor = event.target.result
      if cursor
        if cursor.value.disPercent > 0
          // value is still ok in here
          console.log cursor.value.pid
          $.ajax(
            url: 'api-xxxx'
            dataType: 'json'
            success: (data)->
              $('#remove').on('click', ->
                //value of cursor is already different from the above console.log
                console.log cursor.value.pid
          )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial example, here's the broad structure of your code in simplified pseudocode:

```
openCursor
  if cursor
    console.log(cursor.value)
    ajax
      console.log(cursor.value)
    cursor.continue()
```

Now adding numbers to demonstrate the order everything will run in:

```
1 openCursor
2  if cursor
3    console.log(cursor.value)
4    ajax
6      console.log(cursor.value)
5    cursor.continue()
```

Note that the `continue()` call (#5) happens before the async ajax callback (#6). By the time your ajax callback runs it may have advanced to the next record.

That applies to your first example. Your updated example doesn't have `cursor.continue()` at all - did it just not make the snippet?

Note that one apparent fix - moving the `continue()` call into the ajax callback - won't work because the IDB transaction will auto-commit if there is no work scheduled. Depending on your scenario, you may just be able to capture the cursor value locally, e.g.:

```
openCursor
  if cursor
    console.log(cursor.value)
    value = cursor.value
    ajax
      console.log(value)
    cursor.continue()
```

A fresh copy of the `value` variable would be captured in each call to the openCursor request's success callback.

Comment: For my update, it's just an example so that I can show the `cursor` variable is not working on my 4th level. And of course I still have the `continue()` below those codes.

Answer (score 0):

First guess, but it looks like you're mixing two separate asynchronous things together (ajax and indexed db calls). I don't think this works quite like how you want it to work. You cannot do a request, do an ajax call, and then do another request, and have it work quite like how you want. The callbacks will happen on their own timelines, not in the serial-like callback order you are attempting.

Of course, this is just a guess. I might be totally off on this one.

Comment: I guess so, but the problem only persist if I hit reload on the browser. But the cart's link is being clicked it shows me the actual data.